# Ghostscript preview on macOS

Tags: macos, ghostscript, osx-elcapitan, postscript

I'm trying to get GhostScript 9.20 working on macOS 10.11 El Capitan. The problem is that I can't generate any preview. The PS file is very simple and looks as below:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
% The indispensable Hello World program in PostScript
<<
  /PageSize [595 841]
>> setpagedevice
/Times-Roman findfont 60 scalefont setfont
50 600 moveto
(Hello World) show
showpage
```

When I invoke gs interpreter I get only following result:

[image: console output]

And no preview.

No problems on Ubuntu though. If someone is familiar with working with GhostScript on macOS, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to GhostScript 9.18 has resolved the issue.

Comment: And if you don't report a bug, then whatever is wrong won't get fixed. **Please** report bugs when you find something wrong!

Comment: I'd need the command line you used, but it 'looks like' you've used the bbox device. Since all that device does is report the bounding box of the marks, it won't display anything. At a guess that means that wherever you got the binaries from, they've been compiled without X support, and so you don't have a display device available, hence no display. In the absence of a display device, Ghostscript uses the devices in alphabetical order, bbox usually comes first..... You might be better off pulling the source from Git and compiling it yourself (we don't supply binaries for MacOS).

Comment: @KenS is (as usual) right on the point. Try `gs --help` and you'll probably see `Default output device: bbox`. See if you have  `gs-X11`.